# bundle install and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

I've run "bundle install" on an existing Rails 3 app which has the gems in vendor/cache (I guess they were packed via "bundle package" before) and valid Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files.

What I saw is, it created a folder .bundle in my home dir.

I am using also RVM. When I tried "gem list", I didn't see any of the gems in vendor/cache installed.

Am I doing something wrong? Everywhere the bundler articles say, execute "bundle" or "bundle install" to install the gems in the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files. Is the problem connected with the RVM usage?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Look in the folder returned by `rvm gemdir`. That's where they be installed.

Comment: But they are not there? Should I execute the following: bundle install `rvm gemdir`?

Comment: Basically, bundler creates a dir structure as follows: ruby/1.8/{bin, cache, doc, gems, specifications}. My question then would be, how to make bundle install create this dir structure in the appropriate rvm ruby, i.e. to put the bundle cache. gems, and specifications into the rvm ruby cache, gems, and specifications? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Bundler will use the Gemfile to install to the current gemdir. When the gems are vendored, I *think* you have to do that seperately. Also I dont think gem list will show the gems that are vendored (i could be wrong). Look at the docs. Also, this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in `rvm env gemdir`, also check what you've got set in `.rvmrc` in terms of a gemset.  Do `bundle install` and it should get all the gems.

Check `.bundle` by doing `$ cat .bundle` to see its content , and check if it is copying the gems to `vendor/ruby`.  This will only be the case if `bundle install --path vendor/ruby` was supplied ([Ref](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/02/09/vendor-everything-still-applies/)).

Comment: I found the issue. When you give an arg to bundle install, it keeps installing the gems inside this dir, even if you rm -rf this dir and start from scratch with the pure "bundle install".

Comment: Indeed.  `.bundle` needs to be edited to prevent this from taking effect for future runs of `bundle install`.

Answer (score 6):

If you give an argument to `bundle install`, it will keep installing the gems inside this directory, even if you `rm -rf` that directory and start from scratch with the pure `bundle install`, as noted in Emil's comment. This new directory is taken by default by bundler, and it even supersedes what you declare in the `.rvmrc` file.

To remove this constraint, simply edit the `.bundle/config` file and delete the file declaring `BUNDLE_PATH`, e.g.,

```
BUNDLE_PATH: /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: This is what finally did it for me. After deleting that line in `.bundle/config` it dumped everything in the appropriate `rvm` location like I needed.